# Typescript interface type difference extending Record

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have the following code:

```
interface InterfaceObject {
    a: number;
}
type TypeObject = {
    a: number;
}
type InterfaceObjectTest = InterfaceObject extends Record<string | symbol | number, unknown> ? true : false; // false
type TypeObjectTest = TypeObject extends Record<string | symbol | number, unknown> ? true : false; // true
```

`InterfaceObjectTest` and `TypeObjectTest` represent if their respective types are some kind of object. Since `type` and `interface` are mostly interchangeable, I would have expected both to be the same, true in this case, yet `InterfaceObjectTest` evaluates to false, while `TypeObjectTest` evaluates to true. Furthermore, when replacing `unknown` in the Record value, both evaluate to true.

Can someone explain what difference between `type` and `interface` is causing the different results?

Comment: See [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) and the answers to the linked questions for more information